# Kubernetes cronjob failing to create secret due to RBAC serviceaccount issue

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I'm trying to automate the renewal of ECR credentials and storing the token in a secret via a CronJob. Whenever I run the CronJob I'm getting the following error in the resultant job logs

```
2023-09-14T20:11:20.326837046Z error: failed to create secret secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:cfh:default" cannot create resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "cfh"
```

Interestingly this doesn't seem to fail on the delete step. I'm wondering if maybe the issue has something to do with `kubectl create secret docker-registry` having different Role permissions beyond the standard secret verbs since its of type `docker-registry`, but I'm not sure.

This is what my CronJob YAML looks like:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: ecr-registry-helper
  creationTimestamp: '2023-09-11T00:06:03Z'
  generation: 25
  namespace: cfh
  fields:
    - ecr-registry-helper
    - 0 */10 * * *
    - 'False'
    - 0
    - 11m
    - 3d20h
    - ecr-registry-helper
    - omarxs/awskctl:v1.0
    - <none>
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      namespace: cfh
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
        spec:
          containers:
            - command:
                - /bin/bash
                - '-c'
                - >-
                  ECR_TOKEN=`aws ecr get-login-password --region ${AWS_REGION}`
            
                  NAMESPACE_NAME=cfh
            
                  kubectl delete secret --ignore-not-found regcred -n
                  $NAMESPACE_NAME
            
                  echo "deleted secret"
            
                  kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred
                  --docker-server=https://${AWS_ACCOUNT}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com
                  --docker-username=AWS --docker-password="${ECR_TOKEN}" -n $NAMESPACE_NAME
            
                  echo "Secret was successfully updated at $(date)"
              envFrom:
                - secretRef:
                    name: ecr-registry-helper-secrets
                - configMapRef:
                    name: ecr-registry-helper-cm
              image: omarxs/awskctl:v1.0
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              name: ecr-registry-helper
              terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
              terminationMessagePolicy: File
              _init: false
              __active: true
              resources: {}
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          restartPolicy: Never
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          serviceAccount: default
          serviceAccountName: default
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  schedule: 0 */10 * * *
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 2
  suspend: false
__clone: true
```

As well as my ServiceAccount

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: default
  creationTimestamp: '2023-09-10T22:14:31Z'
  namespace: cfh
  fields:
    - default
    - 0
    - 3d21h
automountServiceAccountToken: false
__clone: true
```

Role

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: '2023-09-11T00:06:03Z'
  name: role-full-access-to-secrets
  namespace: cfh
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resourceNames:
      - regcred
    resources:
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - create
      - delete
      - get
      - list
      - patch
      - update
      - watch
```

And RoleBinding

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: '2023-09-11T00:06:03Z'
  name: default-role-binding
  namespace: cfh
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: role-full-access-to-secrets
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: cfh
```

Comment: If you're trying to automate **cfh** namespace, the resources in cfh cannot be altered and new resources cannot be created. When you try to add a secret, you will get an error. You can create another namespace, refer to [github comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3493#issuecomment-512214553) and add the secret to the required cluster by specifying this namespace when kuberentes RBAC roles are enabled. Also refer to [Restrictions on role binding creation or update](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#restrictions-on-role-binding-creation-or-update).

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing the mark, still working to wrap my brain around RBAC. With that being said can I do this by creating a ClusterRole/RoleBinding for the ServiceAccount that allows the creation/deletion of secrets within the cfh namespace and then mutate the secret now that my ServiceAccount has permission to do so? I'm a little confused on the purpose of creating another namespace in order to mutate a secret in the cfh namespace.

Comment: Your comment helped me figure it out, @VeeraNagireddy , thank you! I'm going to post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @veera-nagireddy for helping me figure it out (see his comment on the original post for some additional context)

The problem was that the `CronJob` itself didn't have the permissions to create/update secrets in the `cfh` namespace despite assuming the role of the `ServiceAccount`. In order to fix this I had to also create a `ClusterRole` & `ClusterRoleBinding` that gave permissions for the `ServiceAccount` to mutate secrets in the `cfh` namespace.

ClusterRole:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: '2023-09-16T02:39:55Z'
  name: ecr-registry-helper-cluster-role
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - create
      - delete
      - update
```

ClusterRoleBinding:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: '2023-09-16T02:42:42Z'
  name: ecr-registry-helper-cluster-role-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ecr-registry-helper-cluster-role
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: cfh
```

After creating these two resources I was able to successfully create the secret.